# Three Tongues of Rock

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> Three tongues of rock
>
> My royal decree
>
> To ancient lore
>
> would hold the key

Who am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are

> the Rosetta stone.

Three tongues of rock
My royal decree

> The text is a decree by a pharaoh, written on rock in three different writing systems.

To ancient lore
would hold the key

> Its discovery was the key to interpreting ancient Egyptian hieroglyphs.

Comment: I'm explicitly looking for the rot13(anzr bs gung cunenbu), but I'll accept this, as the distinction between looking for the rot13(fgbar)or the rot13(cunenbu) may not be clear from the riddle.