# Three Tongues of Rock #2

Tags: riddle, music

Inspired by my last riddle: [Three Tongues of Rock](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/91634/60730)

> One is round
>
> He sings of dark art
>
> One with lips
>
> He gently caresses
>
> The third he sings
>
> Of men who wear dresses

This one should be pretty easy. Enjoy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although others have recognised 2 of the 3 concealed identities correctly, I believe they have not spotted (or explicitly mentioned) the theme, which is:

> Rock acts who are well known for some reason for their **TONGUES** (hence the title, providing an alternative punny meaning to the title of the OP's linked question).

*One is round*
*He sings of dark art*

> As @MatthewWells has pointed out, #1 is the **Rolling Stones** (or specifically **Mick Jagger**, the lead singer). A stone is round, and 'Paint It Black' is one of their best known songs. The band's logo is based on a cartoon image of Mick Jagger's mouth with the tongue protruding:
>
>  [image]

*One with lips*
*He gently caresses*

> As @shoover mentioned, this would be the band **KISS**, with a specific nod towards their frontman, **Gene Simmons**. Simmons is renowned for sticking his tongue out during performances, and at one point there was even a rumour that he had a cow's tongue grafted onto his own in order to make it longer. (This rumour has thus far not been found to be true!)
>
>  [image]

*The third he sings*
*Of men who wear dresses*

> I believe that this final couplet refers to **Aerosmith** - and specifically lead singer **Steven Tyler** - who sing "*Dude (Looks Like a Lady)*". Tyler's tongue is particularly famous for being the subject of many of his lyrics.  For example, "I shove my tongue right between your cheeks" in "*F.I.N.E.*" (see also "*Taste of India*" and "*Back in the Saddle*" for further examples, although note not all readers will be comfortable with the lyrics!).
>
>  [image]

Note that all of these are so renowned for this particular thing that:

> They all feature in a six-item 'listicle' on the [rollingstone.com website](https://www.rollingstone.com/music/music-lists/10-most-famous-rock-roll-tongues-75937/steven-tyler-5-38380/) (from where I have borrowed the images within this answer).

Comment: I did guess the theme, but I'm really bad at remembering trivia on this particular topic.

Answer (score 2):

First one is:

> The Rolling Stones: A rolling stone is round, and they sung "Paint it Black" - a dark art.

Comment: Correct so far.

Answer (score 1):

If Matthew Wells's [answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/91834/4373) for #1 is correct, then #2 and #3 are:

> KISS (lips, caress) and The Kinks ("Lola")

Comment: Your answer for the third one is incorrect.